# No Method Error 'map' for #<Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, arel

I have the following **example** query:

```
source = "(SELECT DISTINCT source.* FROM (SELECT * FROM items) AS source) AS items"
items = Item.select("items.*").from(source).includes([:images])
p items # [#<Item id: 1>, #<Item id:2>]
```

However running:

```
p items.count
```

Results in `NoMethodError: undefined method`map' for Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral`

I appreciate the query is silly, however the non-simplifieid query is a bit too complicated to copy and this was the smallest crashing version I could create. Any ideas?

Comment: Whatever is being returned is a string (that is what Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral inherits from). What does items.class and/or items.inspect show?

Comment: @ScottJShea `items.class` is ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: That is an object inherited class so either way it is not coming out as an enumerable class. Brandan's answer below might be on to something.

Comment: It only occurres when you use `from`, `includes` and `count` together, thrown from active_record/associations/alias_tracker

Comment: I worked around the same problem by calling `preload` instead of `includes`.  This does the same eager-loading, but seems to avoid whatever problem `from/includes/count` has.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you call `all` on that object to essentially cast it to an Array?

```
Item.select("items.*").from(source).includes([:images]).all.count
```

Or perhaps in that case, `size` would be more appropriate. In any case, this will execute the query and load all the objects into memory, which may not be desirable.

---

It looks like the problem is with your `includes([:images])`. On a similar application, I can execute this from the console:

```
> Category.select('categories.*').from('(SELECT DISTINCT source.* FROM (SELECT * FROM categories) AS source) AS categories').count
  (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT source.* FROM (SELECT * FROM categories) AS source) AS categories
```

(Notice that the `count` overrides the SELECT clause, even though I explicitly specified `items.*`. But they're still equivalent queries.)

As soon as I add an `includes` scope, it fails:

```
> Category.select('categories.*').from('(SELECT DISTINCT source.* FROM (SELECT * FROM categories) AS source) AS categories').includes(:projects).count
NoMethodError: undefined method `left' for #<Arel::Nodes::SqlLiteral:0x131d35248>
```

I tried a few different means of acquiring the count, like `select('COUNT(categories.*)')`, but they all failed in various ways. ActiveRecord seems to be falling back on a basic LEFT OUTER JOIN to perform the eager loading, possibly because it thinks you're using some kind of condition or external table to perform the join, and this seems to confuse its normal methods of performing the count. See the end of the section on Eager Loading in the [`ActiveRecord::Associations` docs](http://localhost:8800/~brandan/sdoc/3.1.0-1.9/Rails/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

### My Suggestion

If the join doesn't affect the number of rows returned in the outer query, I'd say your best bet is to execute one query to get the count and one query to get the actual results. We have to do something similar in our application for paging: one query returns the current page of results, and one returns the total number of records matching the filter criteria.

Comment: Calling `all` does indeed work, however this changes the query and forces an execution of loading all objects into memory. Shouldn't it work without calling `all`?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm going to update my answer based on your response, because it got too long for a comment :-)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is Rails #24193 https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24193 and has to do with `from` combined with eager loading. The workaround is to use the form: `Item.select("items.*").from([Arel.sql(source)]).includes([:images])`

Comment: If this problem arises from using `from(...)` and you are doing so for index hinting, you can use an up-to-date version of the activerecord-mysql-index-hint gem which handles this well.